# Why did I lose 20 rep?

Tags: support, reputation

I just "lost" 20 rep, at my profile summary it says "User was removed", what is that?

a screen capture:

[image]

Comment: It happens.  I lost 135 from that user purge apparently.

Comment: 140 lost here and went back under 30k...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These votes correspond to upvotes from a user who now deleted their account. Account deletion undoes all actions of that user. Consequently all they upvotes are removed.

Comment: Does this apply to all the votes of as user, or is there some time period that if passed leaves the rep even if the user was deleted? Like with closed question that if they are old and/or upvoted enough and are deleted the rep remains.

Comment: @IlyaMelamed Meta questions which aren't specific to Skeptics have usually already been asked and answered on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ for example [What does “user was removed” mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126471/139866).

Comment: Konrad, apparently it's possible for moderators to preserve the user's votes and other activities, e.g. depending on why they were deleted (see "so the staff use a special deletion that preserves their votes" in the answer linked above).

Comment: @ChrisW I don’t know which specific deletion triggered Ilya’s rep loss but it’s true that in general we have two options regarding user deletion: normal deletion, which preserves history (i.e. interactions with that user and the community) and just anonymises their contributions, and “burnination” … which is more drastic and normally reserved for spammers or when they user explicitly requests this (even then I’d usually not comply, though: users don’t have exclusive rights to their contents).

Comment: @ChrisW There is a special deletion process available to SE employees that preserves upvotes, but that is only used for high reputation users with a lot of votes.